# jqgrid readyState=4, responseText is right, status=200, statusText=ok! but it does't work

Tags: jqgrid

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>
<%@ page import = "org.json.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.lang.*, java.lang.Math, java.util.Date, com.DBConnectionManager.*,java.sql.*, java.util.*, java.util.Enumeration, java.util.regex.* , javax.mail.*, javax.mail.internet.*" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>
<%@ include file= "../DBheader.jsp" %>// for DB connection

<%

    response.setHeader("content-Type","application/json;charset=utf-8");

    String sql_jqgrid="SELECT g.org_id,g.title,g.date_reg,g.em_name, g.view_count,s.filename, g.download_count FROM org g,orgpds s WHERE g.org_id=s.org_id(+)";

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql_jqgrid);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        int totalpages=0;
        int totalrecords=0;
        int currpage=0;
        double limt=10; 

        while(rs.next()){
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

            object.put("org_id",rs.getString("org_id"));
            object.put("title",rs.getString("title"));
            object.put("date_reg",rs.getString("date_reg"));
            object.put("em_name",rs.getString("em_name"));
            object.put("view_count",rs.getString("view_count"));
            object.put("filename",rs.getString("filename"));
            object.put("download_count",rs.getString("download_count"));

            jsonArray.put(object);
            totalrecords++;
        }

        totalpages= (int)Math.ceil(totalrecords/limt);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        jsonObject.put("totalpages",totalpages);
        jsonObject.put("currpage",1);
        jsonObject.put("totalrecords",totalrecords);
        jsonObject.put("invdata",jsonArray);

        out.clear();
        out.println(jsonObject); 
        out.flush();
%>

<%@ include file= "../DBfotter.jsp" %>// for DB connection
```

And I got this value

> {"currpage":1,"totalrecords":45,"totalpages":5,"invdata":[{"org_id":"4","title":"dfdfdfdff","date_reg":"2009-10-05
>   00:00:00.0","download_count":"0","view_count":"9"},{"org_id":"5","title":"aaa","filename":"aa1.zip","date_reg":"2010-09-29
>   00:00:00.0","download_count":"2","view_count":"26","em_name":"admin"}]}

It's jqGrid Source

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
            url:'../includes/jqgrid/org_list_json.jsp',
            type : "POST",
            datatype:'json',
            jsonReader: {
                root:"invdata",
                page:"currpage",
                total:"totalpages",
                records:"totalrecords",
                cell:"",
                repeatitems : true //search elements in the json data by name 
                },
            loadError:function(xhr,status,error){alert(xhr.state);},
            loadComplete:function(data){alert(data);}, 
            gridComplete:function(data){alert("complete");}, 
            colNames: ['number','contact','date','person','count','download','download_count'],
            colModel: [

                       {name: 'org_id', index: 'org_id',align: 'center', frozen : true, sorttype: 'number', hidden:true},   
                       {name: 'title', index: 'title',align: 'center', sorttype: 'number'},
                       {name: 'date_reg', index: 'date_reg', align: 'left', sorttype: 'date',formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {srcformat:"Y-m-d",newformat:"Y-m-d"}},
                       {name: 'em_name', index: 'em_name', align: 'center'},
                       {name: 'view_count', index: 'view_count', align: 'center'},
                       {name: 'filename', index: 'filename', align: 'left'},
                       {name: 'download_count', index: 'download_count', sorttype: 'number', resizable: true, align: 'center'},
                       ],    

                       rowNum: 10,/
                       rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                       autowidth:true, 
                       width: function(){$("#list").setGridWidth($(this).width(), true);}, 
                       height: '100%',
                       pager: '#pager',
                       gridview: true,
                       rownumbers: false,  
                       sortable: true,
                       rownumbers: true,
                       //multiselect: true, 
                       sortname: 'date_reg',
                       gridview: true,

                       viewrecords: true,
                       scrollOffset: 0,
                       sortorder: 'desc'          


                       });
```

readyState=4, responseText is right, status=200, statusText=ok! but i got a error messege "syntaxError Unexpected token" < (in the chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved question from myself.

I just add "*out.close();*" bottom of org_list_json.jsp
.
after then jqGrid work well.

but I don't know why.

If someone know that, could you tell me?